# How to highlight cells with duplicate values using Excel's inbuilt Conditional Formatting rules, specifically to compare < or >?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

> OS: Windows 10 Pro Version 20H2 (OS Build: 19042.1165)
> Application: Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 Version 2107 (Build 14228.20250)

***Please bear with me for posting a non-code-related question. I posted this question on SU and I sincerely appreciate the members who gave their answers but I just couldn't get a satisfactory answer there. If moderators decided to close this post, you may follow this [link to my post at SU](https://superuser.com/questions/1671085/how-to-highlight-cells-with-duplicate-values-using-excels-inbuilt-conditional-f/).

When using Excel's inbuilt Conditional Formatting rules to highlight cells with duplicate values, specifically to compare `<` or `>`, it doesn't seem to work on my end.

I tried searching the internet about this issue to no avail.

Using the table below to visualize an Excel spreadsheet,

| Value | Value |
| --- | --- |
| < | < |
| > | > |

I highlighted cells `A1:B3`, clicked on `Home Tab`>`Conditional Formatting`>`Highlight Cells Rules`>`Duplicate Values…`,>`OK`. Regardless if I choose `Duplicate` or `Unique` on the dropdown options, it just won't work here. Only the first row is being formatted.

It works fine though when using conditional formatting formula.

I'd like to know, with your help, if this issue is isolated, or am I just missing something here? Could it be a bug?

Thank you all very much..

Comment: Probably a bug.

Comment: @BigBen, my thoughts exactly..

Answer (score 0):

One way to highlight duplicate rows in a multi-column array, change the rule type to "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and enter this formula:

```
=$A1=$B1
```

$ tells the formula to always reference columns "A" and "B"
Because there is no $ before the row number, it becomes dynamic and the condition is applied to each row in the array it applies to.

Comment: thank you for sharing your idea. As I have mentioned in my post, conditional formatting formula works. As a matter of fact, I used the same formula as yours. What I would like to know is if this problem (specifically with the method described in the post; meaning, not any other method) is isolated—like only me or a handful of users experience it? Or is it a bug? Or is it me doing it incorrectly? Things like that..

Answer (score 0):

The conditional Formatting is performing as it is designed to function.

The reason selecting the duplicate conditional formatting option does not highlight rows where the columns match is because it is not looking at each row in the array separately, it is looking at the entire data set to see if there are duplicated values. So if you have a value in more then one cell (any row or column), it will highlight all cells with multiple values.

```
     A    B
1    a    b     A1 will be highlighted
2    c    a     A2 and B2 will be highlighted
3    d    c     B3 will be highlighted
```

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts. That's the `Conditional Formatting` behavior that I was looking for. I actually know how it behaves, exactly like how you explained it. You explained it beautifully, by the way, however, I was looking for a response that explains why the method explained in my post doesn't seem to work SPECIFICALLY with these conditional operators: `<` and `>`; and potentially even `=`, `>=`, and `<=` doesn't seem to work as well. If I remember correctly, the only conditional operator that works with the method explained in the post was `<>`..

Comment: as BigBen have already mentioned, it might be a bug, which is exactly I have been thinking since the last time I tried it. I still believe it to be a bug unless someone gives a compelling explanation..